# How can Two or more columns sum and display in third column

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Seen **following image** as an mark data i want **two columns data sum** and generate in **new column to display** it.
How can it possible in **Kendo for Angular 4**.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new computed property for your data model, that will return the sum of the needed properties.

```
export class DataModel {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    get sum() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    }
}
```

Then, add a column as you added for the other properties.

Or, use template property provided by Kendo.

Version 1:

```
columns: [{
            field: "PropA",
            title: "Prop A"
          },
          {
            field: "PropB",
            title: "Prop B"
          },
          {
            field: "Sum",
            template: "{{dataItem.PropA + dataItem.PropB}}"
          }]
```

Version 2:

```
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
        <kendo-grid-column field="PropA" title="PropA"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="PropB" title="PropB"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Sum" title="Sum">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                 {{dataItem.PropA + dataItem.PropB}}
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

Comment: i want it on binding html

Comment: Updated answer can use in angular ver. 2.0 or above  ?

Comment: Yes. I added a 3rd version.

Comment: Thanks @MariusOrha